# How to Change the font style and size UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: swift, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I have have currently created a toolbar with a size button with pop-up along with a date picker when the corresponding text field is interacted with.

Screenshot:

[image]

I want to be able to change the font style and size of the button.

Code Snippets:

UIToolBar Creation:

```
/*** ToolBar setup DatePicker ***/
    let toolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height/6, self.view.frame.size.width, 40.0))
    toolBar.layer.position = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.size.width/2, y: self.view.frame.size.height-20.0)
    toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default
    toolBar.tintColor = UIColor.init(red: 0, green: 122/255, blue: 1, alpha: 1.0)
    toolBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
```

UIBarButton Declaration:

```
let okBarBtn = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Done, target: self, action: "donePressed:")
```

Comment: Please do make an effort to examine the docs before asking a question on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Call [`setTitleTextAttributes:forState:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarItem_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBarItem/setTitleTextAttributes:forState:).

Comment: Could you please elaborate futher